# Getting error instalingl wget in RHEL EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, wget

Getting this message when trying to install wget in RHEL EC2 instance. How to resolve this?

[image]

> Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhui-client-config-server-8': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://rhui3.ap-south-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/mirror/protected/rhui-client-config/rhel/server/8/x86_64/os [Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds]

Comment: I would check that you can actually reach the internet from this instance.  There is probably a firewall or security group rule that is blocking outgoing connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up SSH for the EC2 instance, try and SSH into the machine, and try

`curl -I https://www.google.com`
and if it times out, you perhaps can't connect to the internet.

You need to check if the relevant Security Group has an outbound rule allowing connections to the internet:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console#security-group-rules

There are a few useful hints in https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4656371 as well, if the issue is related to your subscription.